# Checking whether array is array, but taking into account arguments object

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I am doing some exercises for a coding school and one of those is reimplementing _.first from Underline. My code is not passing one last test, which is "Should return an empty array if array is not an array", which should seem easy.

However, there is another test which is "Should work on an arguments object" and if I pass the second test, I cannot pass the first one and I cannot think of any other implementation atm. 
Here is my code for both of these tests:

```
function (array, n) {
  let resultingArray = [];
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, 1);
  let args2 = args[0];
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
        for (let key in args2) {
          if (args2[key] == 'a' || args2[key] == 'b') {
            resultingArray.push(args2[key]);
          }
        }
    } else {
      resultingArray = [];
    }
  } else if (array == undefined) {
    resultingArray = [];
  } else if (n == undefined || n <= 0) {
    resultingArray = array.slice(0, 1);
  } else {
    resultingArray = array.slice(0, n);
  }
  return resultingArray;
};
```

The test gives me back the following:

```
should return an empty array if array is not an array ‣
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object._.first (index.js:14:15)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:34:9)_.first().should.eql([]);
_.first(null).should.eql([]);
_.first(1).should.eql([]);
```

Would appreciate any help on the subject, thanks in advance!

Comment: `[].hasOwnProperty('length');` is `true`

Comment: "*`if (!Array.isArray(array))`*" doesn't make sense

Comment: What is going on with those `args` and `args2`? AFAICS, `args2 === array`.

Comment: Is your function complete? Because it's missing the closing brace and a return statement too.

Comment: @Bergi 
`if (!Array.isArray(array))` was using this to set a condition for when the variable that is passed into the function is not an array. I do not set the "array" that is passed into the function, it is set by the test.js which I do not touch

Comment: @oniramarf it's not complete, I am going to update to include all the code

Comment: @Konstantin Ah now with the `else` case it makes more sense. The conditions are still in the wrong order, though.

Comment: @Bergi how would you order them?

Comment: You need to do the `Array.isArray(array)` check last, after `array == undefined` and probably also after the `n` range check.

Comment: @Bergi changing the order and tweaking a few things has helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the problem exists, is because you aren't checking if `array` is `null` or `undefined` before using it as an object in `array.hasOwnProperty('length')`. Doing the change shown below should fix the problem.

`(array.hasOwnProperty('length'))` => `(array != null && array.hasOwnProperty('length'))`

Note that `!=` is used rather than `!==` so that both `null` and `undefined` will get checked. If you only want to loop through an Object, then you can instead use this check `typeof array === "object"`.

Finally, I would recommend using `typeof array[Symbol.iterator] === "function"` instead of `array.hasOwnProperty('length')`. To see if the property can actually be looped for, rather than checking if it has a `length` property. (This is assuming that you are using ES6 though, since symbols don't exist in ES5)

Comment: I cannot define array or n as it is defined by external sheet test.js, as seen here
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object._.first (index.js:14:15)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:34:9)`


As for the changing the `if (!Array.isArray(array))` to `if (Array.isArray(array))` I have other tests to pass relating to arrays and my code passes it, I have trouble with these 2 tests specifically and they both concern other elements than arrays (arguments or objects or primitives)

Comment: Then how about changing `if (array.hasOwnProperty('length')) {` to `if (typeof array !== "undefined" && array.hasOwnProperty('length')) {` ?

Comment: Also, I've edited the answer. Can you define `array` and `n` like that?

Comment: No, I cannot touch the array or n at all. 
I've checked for the `typeof array !== 'undefined'` and it works, but the test then throws an error as it `cannot read 'hasOwnProperty' of null` either, I am going to try going your way and will get back to you

Comment: I decided to rearrange the order of the conditionals and then using your logic added `!== undefined, !== null and typeof array !== 'number'` and yes, it now passes all of the tests! Thanks!